# Intellij IDEA : no new java package menu option

Tags: java, intellij-idea, editor

Environment :

- Windows 10
- Intellij IDEA 2021.3.2 (Community Edition)

I'v setup a new Spring project and on right clicking on the directory structure to create a new java package there's no more new / package nor class option.
I already faced that issue and the solution was to "Mark Directory as" the src directory as "sources root" (by right clicking on the src directory).
But now this "Mark Directory as" option has disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Strange : deleting the .idea root directory and restarting the IDE solved the problem.